# Best way of organising load/save functions in terms of static/non-static

Tags: c++

I have a class which defines a historical extraction on a database:

```
class ExtractionConfiguration  
{  
    string ExtractionName;  
    time ExtractionStartTime;  
    time ExtractionEndTime;

    // Should these functions be static/non-static?
    // The load/save path is a function of ExtractionName
    void SaveConfigruation();
    void LoadConfiguration();
}
```

These ExtractionConfigurations need to be saved to/loaded from disk. What is the best way of organising the save/load functions in terms of static/non-static? To me, it is clear that SaveConfiguration() should be a member function. However with LoadConfiguration(), does it make more sense to call

```
ExtractionConfiguration newExtraction;  
newExtraction.LoadConfiguration();
```

and have a temporary empty instance or make the load function static

```
static ExtractionConfiguration LoadConfiguration(string filename);
```

and just call

```
ExtractionConfiguration newExtraction = ExtractionConfiguration::LoadConfiguration(filename);
```

which feels neater to me, but breaks the 'symmetry' of the load/save mechanism (is this even a meaningful/worthwhile consideration?).

I suppose asking for the 'best' answer is somewhat naive. I am really trying to get a better understanding of the issues involved here.

P.S. This is my first question on SO, so if I have not presented it correctly, please let me know and I will try and make the problem clearer.

Comment: Welcome. To format as code, you indent the section of code by 4 spaces or 1 tab. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Thanks Kenny, I was *sure* I was missing a trick with the formatting there!

Comment: You should use shorter names. E.g. just save and load, since they are already inside the class. Not everybody uses Intellisense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [Boost.Serialization style](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) serialization function that avoids having separate functions for saving and loading (even if you don't use the library itself).

In this approach you can pass the function any type of object that has operator&, to perform an operation on all the member variables. One such object might save the data to a file, another might load from a file, third might print the data on console (for debugging, etc).

If you wish to keep separate functions, having them as non-static members might be a better option. For the saving function this is obvious, but loading is a different matter because there you need to construct the object. However, quite commonly loading is done by default-constructing and then calling the load non-static member function, for symmetry reasons, I guess.

Having the loading as a function that returns a new object seems better in some ways, but then you need to decide how it returns the object. Is it allocated by new, or simply returned by value? Returning by value requires the object to be copyable and returning a pointer mandates the resource management scheme (cannot just store the object on stack).

Comment: Good call on the serialization. It's not hard to roll your own serialize functions if you don't like boost's for some reason. @Rodion, Consider making a constructor or initialize function that takes the filename as an argument if you want to avoid extra copies. You could keep your load or deserialize function as a helper.

Comment: I'll have a look at the Serialization library, it sounds useful. Unfortunately my boss has a "don't believe the hype" attitude to OOP and in fact almost anything that you haven't coded personally, which is why I am using a basic load/save structure.

Your points on the load/save pretty much match my feelings. I am going to go for non-static load/save. As for what to return when using a static load, I think returning by value is best. As you say, passing pointers dictates your method of resouce management, which would shackle your design over something fairly minor.